# ntpdate -d seems successful, but ntpdate returns no server suitable

Tags: ntp

I've got a system that is not running ntpd on which I'm attempting to update the clock using ntpdate. The system is an appliance that appears to be CentOS 6 based.

When I run `ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org`, I get:

```
8 Sep 17:52:05 ntpdate[7445]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

However, when I do `ntpdate -d 0.pool.ntp.org`, I get:

```
8 Sep 17:55:14 ntpdate[9499]: ntpdate 4.2.2p1@1.1570-o Fri Nov 18 13:21:21 UTC 2011 (1)
Looking for host 0.pool.ntp.org and service ntp
host found : 4.53.160.75
transmit(4.53.160.75)
receive(4.53.160.75)
transmit(4.53.160.75)
receive(4.53.160.75)
transmit(4.53.160.75)
receive(4.53.160.75)
transmit(4.53.160.75)
receive(4.53.160.75)
transmit(4.53.160.75)
transmit(64.16.214.60)
receive(64.16.214.60)
transmit(64.16.214.60)
receive(64.16.214.60)
transmit(64.16.214.60)
receive(64.16.214.60)
transmit(64.16.214.60)
receive(64.16.214.60)
transmit(64.16.214.60)
transmit(54.236.224.171)
receive(54.236.224.171)
transmit(54.236.224.171)
receive(54.236.224.171)
transmit(54.236.224.171)
receive(54.236.224.171)
transmit(54.236.224.171)
receive(54.236.224.171)
transmit(54.236.224.171)
transmit(50.22.155.163)
receive(50.22.155.163)
transmit(50.22.155.163)
receive(50.22.155.163)
transmit(50.22.155.163)
receive(50.22.155.163)
transmit(50.22.155.163)
receive(50.22.155.163)
transmit(50.22.155.163)
server 4.53.160.75, port 123
stratum 2, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [4.53.160.75], delay 0.03160, dispersion 0.00005
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d7b867d0.f9841075  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:37:20.974
originate timestamp: d7b86c03.b6a49dae  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:15.713
transmit timestamp:  d7b86c02.7e12a51e  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:14.492
filter delay:  0.03189  0.03188  0.03172  0.03160
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 1.218061 1.217856 1.218023 1.217968
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.03160, dispersion 0.00005
offset 1.217968

server 64.16.214.60, port 123
stratum 2, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [64.16.214.60], delay 0.04886, dispersion 0.00006
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d7b86425.55948a73  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:21:41.334
originate timestamp: d7b86c03.f7d91219  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:15.968
transmit timestamp:  d7b86c02.bed42c3c  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:14.745
filter delay:  0.04919  0.04892  0.04912  0.04886
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 1.210967 1.210879 1.210967 1.210836
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.04886, dispersion 0.00006
offset 1.210836

server 54.236.224.171, port 123
stratum 3, precision -20, leap 00, trust 000
refid [54.236.224.171], delay 0.04878, dispersion 0.00011
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d7b864eb.b06fee7d  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:24:59.689
originate timestamp: d7b86c04.2b9d2547  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:16.170
transmit timestamp:  d7b86c02.f1e80bed  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:14.944
filter delay:  0.04977  0.04950  0.04878  0.04887
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 1.214091 1.214069 1.213755 1.213750
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.04878, dispersion 0.00011
offset 1.213755

server 50.22.155.163, port 123
stratum 2, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [50.22.155.163], delay 0.07384, dispersion 0.00005
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d7b869c9.2b3f3d0b  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:45:45.168
originate timestamp: d7b86c04.75472e97  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:16.458
transmit timestamp:  d7b86c03.384a83b1  Mon, Sep  8 2014 17:55:15.219
filter delay:  0.07408  0.07414  0.07384  0.07387
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 1.214115 1.214122 1.214012 1.214069
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.07384, dispersion 0.00005
offset 1.214012

 8 Sep 17:55:15 ntpdate[9499]: step time server 4.53.160.75 offset 1.217968 sec
```

Based on my previous searches, this result (with the various receive() lines and the offset) suggests that it is communicating with the remote NTP servers correctly (not blocked by a firewall). So, why does it not update my clock when I run it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try running it as:

```
ntpdate -u 0.pool.ntp.org
```

The `-u` configures `ntpdate` to use an unprivileged port, which it always does when you use the `-d` option.

Therefore, it it works with `-u` and `-d` but not without either, I'd double check your firewalls.

From the man page:

> **-u** Direct ntpdate to use an unprivileged port for outgoing packets. This is most useful when behind a firewall that blocks incoming traffic to privileged ports, and you want to synchronize with hosts beyond the firewall. Note that the -d option always uses unprivileged ports.

Comment: This did it. I'm guessing I have a more restrictive firewall somewhere beyond this server, which I was missing because -d worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

add this rule in iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1025-65535
```

Comment: Hello Norberto. This may well solve the problem but it would be very helpful if you could edit your answer to explain why it does so.

Comment: To the downvoter: a reason for the downvote would be courteous and quite possibly helpful. IMO there's nothing intrinsically wrong with this answer that a little explanation couldn't solve.